# Tp Players To a Certain Block When They First Spawn

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

On my Vanilla Minecraft server I want players to TPed to the center spawn block when they join I know that if you set the world spawn players will spawn within a 20 block radius of that point, I was thinking that if I hook up a command block to tp people within a 20 block radius to the center block I just don't know how to go about it. I need it to be compact because the spawn is a floating airship and I cant have it hanging into the passageway below. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the default gamemode to "adventure" and players will spawn at the exact world spawn rather than within a radius.

```
/defaultgamemode adventure
```

In 1.9+, the `spawnRadius` gamerule sets how many blocks outward that the player can spawn within without having to change the default gamemode.

```
/gamerule spawnRadius 0
```